# How to properly reset a browser styling (like <button>)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A lot of sources want me to reset a html by resetting a ton of individual properties, like here: https://css-tricks.com/overriding-default-button-styles/

What I can also do in CSS, is just:
`button: {all: unset;}`

Is this somehow an anti-pattern? I know that I need a polyfill for that, but it's not like almost all projects aren't using those anyways.

EDIT: The comments told me that it is too unspecific, what my intention is. I want to have a clear and solid markup. I had a `<span>` tag that contained an icon that acted as button. I got the (valid) feedback, that this is a button and should therefore be wrapped by `<button>` tags. When I did that, the button tag obviously brought some browser look-and-feel with it, like a background and a border that made the icon look weird. I had to remove that and was wondering, if I should remove specific css properties or just all of them.

Comment: May take a look at [reset css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) hope it helps

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? As written now, the question sounds like you want to know what you want to do. Too broad and primarily opinion based.

Comment: @MrLister I adapted the question to give a bit of background.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, after 20 years of doing this, that with `CSS`, anti-patterns tend to be contextual.

### Use { all: unset; }

Let's say you're building a new `CSS` library for modern browsers. In this case, I would want to strip `button` down to the bare metal, to catch every edge case I possibly could. We're telling people, *Hey, if you use my awesome library, you can use it anywhere and expect machine-like rendering uniformity*. There's a lot of pressure to get it right the first time. Otherwise, we'll be patching our library every other week as some empassioned Opera Mini user comes pounding on the door.

### Don't use it

For many of us, we're building out components or e-commerce widgets. Many of us are not building opinionated CSS libraries. If you're someone like me who pushes a lot of pixels for other people or for side projects, using that rule would just be a waste of time. I'd probably end up adding back a bunch of styles `{ all: unset; }` would have removed. When I was a younger developer, I usually chose the path of convention over context and practicality, convinced that the way to victory was through discipline and pain. Often, I ended up misusing my time—time better spent working on other things.

### So what do I use?

The biggest general offenders when using `button`:

- unwanted `background-color`
- unwanted borders with 90s styles (outset? inset?)
- loss of inherited `font-family`
- the button-like appearance on some older mobile browsers

Here is my typical default `button` styling:

```css
.button-reset {
  background-color: transparent;  
  border: none;
  font-family: inherit; 
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;  
}
```

**Aside:** I like to add `cursor: pointer` to all my `button`s. It feels more satisfying to me for the cursor to change when hovering a clickable element.

Comment: I agree with most of your post, e.g. about resets usually being overkill. I mean, what's the use of making a button look like plain text? But I'm not sure you are answering the OP's question.

Comment: @MrLister I will elaborate more.

Comment: +1 for your answer, but the core question is, which way should I go? Should I just overwrite some properties of button? A future browser update might introduce `padding: 500px` for `<button>` (won't happen, but you know what I mean), what am I going to do then? This would force me to later also override the padding manually. On the other hand, I want to have some stuff like `cursor: pointer` on hover. I still am not sure if there is a best practice. Might be that there is none, but both scenarios come with major drawbacks.

Comment: @codepleb My answer is derived from my experience. Always stick to semantic markup. As an accessibility expert, I'm dogmatic about that point.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of unset is powerful and almost fully supported on the web. Go for it unless you have to create IE support code since both 6-10 and 11 dont accept it
Your can also check more detailed check here: https://caniuse.com/#search=unset